# Remover um slide de um swiper pela class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Tenho o seguinte swiper:

```
var swiperBanner = new Swiper('.swiper-container-banner', {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    speed: 1200,
    loop: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    freeMode: false,
    preventClicks: true,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 5000
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true
    }
});
```

nas imagens de slide tenho alguns com a classe 'mobile' e outros 'desktop', gostaria de remover os slides mobile em telas maiores, e o desktop em telas menores, mais não estou encontrando uma forma, ja tentei `display: none` mais não funcionou

Comment: Use Srcset nas imagens do slíder acho que pode resolver pro seu saco a questão de uma imagem para cada tamanho de tela

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `CSS @media screen` para definir uma regra do que você considera tela *mobile* e *desktop*. No exemplo abaixo, eu defino tela *desktop* a partir de `480px`, logo, nesta regra, as telas consideradas *mobile* serão de `0px` a `479px`. Então basta alternar entre `display: none` e `display: block` nas classes:

```
<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
   .desktop{
      display: block;
   }
   .mobile{
      display: none;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
   .desktop{
      display: none;
   }
   .mobile{
      display: block;
   }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Como coloquei na descrição, ja tentei dessa forma, mais não funciona, agradeço a tentativa